# Trying to include archived data in a Access 2007 query, not letting me run due to duplicate table titles?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have recently tried to archive my data to another table so that my working table is smaller and easier to work with, I have a query that combines my *Clients* table with my *Trips* table so that my reports can grab data from both tables.

I don't understand SQL at all but I'm hoping it's a simple fix that I will be able to understand. Everything I have tried has been with linking in Design view, I haven't tried anything in SQL view.

If more information is needed please ask me for it as I'm not actually sure what I need to be giving.

```
SELECT clients1.clientid, 
       clients1.client, 
       trip.DATE, 
       clients1.contactname, 
       clients1.address, 
       clients1.town, 
       clients1.county, 
       clients1.[post code], 
       clients1.phonenumber, 
       clients1.[mobile number], 
       trip.vehicle, 
       trip.tripid, 
       trip.[pick up], 
       trip.return, 
       trip.destination, 
       trip.startpoint, 
       trip.startmileage, 
       trip.finishmileage, 
       trip.driver, 
       trip.price, 
       trip.method, 
       trip.invoice, 
       trip.paid, 
       trip.extra, 
       trip.extracost, 
       [startpoint] & " to " & [destination] AS Trip, 
       trip.invoicedate, 
       trip.wheelchair, 
       trip.babyseat, 
       trip.pushchairs, 
       trip.paymentslipno, 
       [price] + [extracost]                 AS TripCost, 
       trip.[not shown on contacts], 
       trip.[extras vat], 
       trip.vat, 
       trip.[extras vat], 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].tripid, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].DATE, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].clientid, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].[pick up], 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].return, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].startpoint, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].destination, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].driver, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].vehicle, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].startmileage, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].finishmileage, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].invoice, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].price, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].vat, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].extracost, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].[extras vat], 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].method, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].sent, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].paid, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].invoicedate, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].notes, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].extra, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].paymentslipno, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].wheelchair, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].babyseat, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].passengers, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].pushchairs, 
       [trip archive 2015 & 2016].[not shown on contacts] 
FROM   (clients1 
        INNER JOIN trip 
                ON clients1.clientid = trip.clientid) 
       INNER JOIN [trip archive 2015 & 2016] 
               ON clients1.clientid = [trip archive 2015 & 2016].clientid 
WHERE  (( ( trip.invoice ) LIKE "*" & [enter invoice no:] & "*" )) 
ORDER  BY clients1.client, 
          trip.DATE, 
          trip.tripid;
```

Comment: What is the specific error you are receiving? You can always rename dupe columns with `AS` operator. However, why do you need to list all of the. Maybe a union query (stacking tables) would help?

Comment: Do you realize that your reports can already grab data from multiple tables?  A report data source is just a query, no different than what you're attempting here.  Sometimes an archive will indeed have consolidated data, but there also should be no need to combine it all into one table.

Comment: Also, what is the destination table?  From the table names, it looks like `[trip archive 2015 & 2016]` is the archive table, but you are linking to rather than insert into it.  You probably need an INSERT INTO statement.  In the Access query designer it is called an Append query.

Comment: Need to UNION [trip] and [trip archive] if you want to retrieve from both tables. No builder or wizard for UNION. Must type into SQLView. I think you will regret going the archive table route. How many records in these tables?